Почему ошибка? Как исправить?
Написал код
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect('gh.db')
cursor=conn.cursor()

В итоге показывает ошибку в 3 строке conn=sqlite3.connect('gh.db')
В чем проблема и как исправить?

Что за ошибка? Добавьте полный текст ошибки в вопрос

Начните изучение питона  с синтаксиса питона. Вот зачем вы там отступ сделали?

@AlexeyTen, отступ сделал не ТС, а
aleksandr barakin: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1589957/revisions

@wchistow в оригинале он был, просто не было форматирования  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/f48c0b01-161c-44ba-ba45-9aca6ca5ae41/view-source

@AlexeyTen Ну ошибка вроде всё-равно не про это, но подождём полный трейс.

Полный трейс ошибки в студию! (Прямо в вопрос.)

https://habr.com/ru/articles/754400/ почитайте этот сайтик там есть все необходимое для вас
с кодом попробуйте так:
import sqlite3

# Создаем подключение к базе данных (файл my_database.db будет создан)
connection = sqlite3.connect('my_database.db')

connection.close()


Ваш код не отличается ничем от кода в вопросе, непонятно, как он исправит ошибку (которую мы по-прежнему не знаем)

вы не закрыли подклучение к базе данных

Хм. Если речь не об ошибке питона, а о диагностике проблем самой IDE, то вы может даже и правы, такой совет IDE может давать. Но мы по-прежнему не имеем информации, что же за ошибка у автора вопроса.

в принцыпе да  согласен
